# How to upgrade a package to the latest version?

Tags: 18.04

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)` and I installed `patroni` using command sudo `apt-get install patroni`.

The version of `patroni` that got installed is `1.61` but I found that this version has a bug and therefore wanted to upgrade to the latest version of the `patroni` but through `apt`

So I looked here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/patroni and found that the latest stable version that I could install is `Patroni 1.6.4`

My question is how can I install this latest version of `patroni` ?

When I try to look for available versions of `patroni` I get the following output:

```
sudo apt list -a patroni
Listing... Done
patroni/bionic-pgdg,bionic-pgdg,now 1.6.1-1.pgdg18.04+1 all [installed]
patroni/bionic,bionic 1.4.2-2ubuntu1 all
```

Comment: @Terrance I installed it using the following commands:

`echo​ ​"deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main"​ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

`wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

`apt-get -y install postgresql-client-11 postgresql-11 patroni python3-consul`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @N0rbert There's no reason to squash this question with that placebo duplicate link because the patroni 1.6.4 package from 20.04 can also be installed in 18.04 without any unmet dependency problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually download patroni 1.6.4 from the officially Ubuntu 20.04 repositories and install it in Ubuntu 18.04 by running the following commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/patroni_1.6.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt remove patroni
sudo apt install ./patroni_1.6.4-2ubuntu1_all.deb
```